# CSS import not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a file that thickbox loads remotely, as part of a frontend admin interface, but the style's won't load. I have a popup.css file that looks like:

```
body#pop {
    width:400px;
    min-height:200px;
}


div.pop {
    width:100%;
}


div.pop #hd {
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0, 159, 245, 1);
    background:rgba(0, 159, 245, .5);
}


div.pop #hd #title {
    padding-top:5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}


div.pop #bd {
    background:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    font-size:11px;
}


div.pop #ft {
    height:30px;
    border-top:1px solid rgba(0, 159, 245, 1);
}


div.pop #ft #buttons {
    float:right;
}


div.pop #ft #buttons input[type='submit'] {
    background:rgba(0, 159, 245, .5);
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    border:1px solid rgba(0, 159, 245, 1);
    opacity:.9;
}


div.pop #ft #buttons input[type='submit']:hover {
    opacity:1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

and a popup.php (currently just a template) that looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="/resources/css/popup.css" />

    </head>
    <body id="pop">

        <div class="pop">
            <div id="hd">
                <span id="title">Modify Homepage</span>
            </div>

            <div id="bd">
                <p>
                    To modify the homepage image, go to the grid, select an image, select "admin:Edit" from the tools bar, and click, "set as homepage".
                </p>
            </div>

            <div id="ft">
                <div id="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" name="subXxx" class="submit" onclick="tb_remove()" value="Okay" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

But the css styles from the stylesheet (popup.css) aren't being applied to the file, thickboxed or just viewing it directly in the browser, no overlay. I'm rather experienced at all this, and I'm completely lost. What's happening, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check with Firebug (NET tab) if the CSS file was actually loaded?

Comment: It is likely that it is caching your older version of the css file.

Restart your browser and I think it would load correctly.

Comment: I just checked Firebug; it isn't loading. Why might this be happening?

Comment: And @inium, I tried that, no success.

Comment: Try it in a different browser and you will know if it a problem with your code or something else

Comment: I've tried in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. None display it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write `href=""` instead of `src=""` like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/popup.css" />
```

Comment: Oh my god. I think this is a sign that it's time for some sleep, or a break at least. Haha. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

What is the complete path to the remote css file?

Is '/resources/css/popup.css' a valid path to the location of the css file?

First you need to type the valid url in browser to see if the css actually there at that location.

Let us know the url, we all can check.

Comment: It's on my laptop. The site isn't live yet, it's just on a local configuration of MAMP. The url is valid, I'm positive; it's where it's supposed to be, that was the second thing I checked.

Comment: And even when I drop the css from the external file into <style> tags, it still doesn't work. The only way it has is using a style attribute on every individual tag.